# Time series predictions look suspiciously good

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, prediction, keras

I am working on a time series forecasting problem. For this, I am training a recurrent neural network in Keras (mostly following the guidelines from [this blog post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/) by Jason Brownlee).

My problem comes when predicting on test data. The **model seems to perform well in every situation** :

- if **trained on real data and tested on real data** (which is what I am expecting after all)
  [image]
- if **trained on a random walk and tested on real data** (which is suspicious to me)
  [image]
- if **trained on real data and tested on a random walk** (which is suspicious again)
  [image]

When I say "the model performs well", I mean several things :

- the inferred values follow the rapid changes in the test values, and it gets better with model complexity (RNN depth, RNN breadth, number of epochs, etc.).
- all comparison metrics (RMSE, MAE, MAPE) are consistently better with the trained model than with the baseline persistence model, even with very shallow and under-trained networks

**How is this possible ?** Is there an error in my code ? Or are RNN *that* good at predicting ?

Code is available on [this Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Lu7DgN9gBeGib0BAqV8sBLwcV4qMic3D) for testing.

Thank you in advance for your guidance !

Comment: This seems likely to be a coding problem, and so would be off-topic here. If it's not, I think we might need more information to understand the conceptual problem, but I could be wrong since it's not my area. Either way, I commend you for being suspicious and doing the checks in the second and third figures; those were good ideas.

Comment: @mkt Thank you ! 
I am currently investigating on the statefulness of the RNN hoping to find something.

Comment: @mkt After days of searching, I did not find anything that adresses my problem. Would it be relevant to ask this question on Machine Learning SE (or even Code Review) ? Consequently, should I delete the present question ?

Comment: I'm not sure where it is best suited, since I'm not familiar with the other SEs. As I said, it would be a good question for here if you edited it to include more detail about the problem. Doing so may well get more people to take a look. But if you'd like to try the others as well, you could request that the question be migrated to another one. Don't post it on more than one SE at a time, though.

Comment: @mkt Turning the code inside out (and re-writing a decent amount of it) allowed me to pin down the culprit: it boils down to an array index error, which gave the model access to an extra column - namely, the output column... After removing it, the predictive performance free-falled, as expected.

Should I delete the question ? Or should I answer to it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what's best, so I've flagged it for moderator attention. One of the mods would be better placed to address this.

Comment: @mkt Thank you for your guidance all along !

Comment: Happy to help and I'm glad you fixed your problem!